# How to reduce spacing between navigation links

Tags: html, css

I've got a navigation bar and I want it to stretch across the page, I've got a responsive layout (although this is not reflected below, I've cut our the necessary code which builds my nav) and on my mobile view I would like the navigation bar to drop down to a separate line which its does.

However what I want to do is have a background color on these `<a>` tags but to create an effect that they are joined together.

I've tried to use padding but this hasn't worked for me it has instead increased the overall height, any ideas?

My code is below and any help would be appreciated

or view my jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7Gu4Y/)

test.html

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>iManage</title>
    <style>
    @charset "utf-8";
    /* CSS Document */
    /********************************
    * CSS Reset                     *
    *********************************/
    html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
    a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
    article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
    menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        font-size: 100%;
        font: inherit;
        vertical-align: baseline;
    }
    /* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
    article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
        display: block;
    }

    body {

        line-height: 1;
        background-color:#EEEEEE;
            font-family:Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

    }

    ol, ul {
        list-style: none;
    }

    blockquote, q {
        quotes: none;
    }

    blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
    q:before, q:after {
        content: '';
        content: none;
    }

    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
    }


    /* Styles */
    header h1 {
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;

    }

    header nav {
        width:100%;
        background-color:#232527;

    }

    .maina > li  {

    }

    header nav a:link {
    font-size:12px;
    font-size:12px;
    width:120px;
    padding:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#98bf21;
    }


    header {
    width:auto;
    min-height:50px;
    background-color:#374348;
    }

    header > h1 {
        font-size:24px;
        font-weight:300;
        color:#FFF;
        padding:10px;
        font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;  
    }

    .main a {

    }

    .maina > li  {
        display:inline; 
        list-style:none;    
    }

    header > nav {
        font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
        text-align:center;
        height:auto;
        border:medium #999;
        float: left;
    }

    .clear:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }

    header nav a:link {
    color:#CCC;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    border:medium #CCC; 
    }

    header nav a:visited {
    color:#FFF;
    }


    header nav a:active {
    color:#7e7975;
    }

    header nav a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
    }
    </style>
    </head>


    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <header class="clear">
    <h1>iManage</h1>
      <nav>
            <ul class="maina">
                <li><a href="index">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="Projects">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="Settings">Settings</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div id="maincontentWrapper">


    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your using `display:inline`. Use 'float:left' instead. Using `display:inline` always creates unwanted margins for unknown reasons to me.

Comment: @deathApril what are those reasons, I would like to know.

Comment: the reason is because when you make an object inline it will treat it like a word in a sentence and any spaces between the words in a sentence are displayed - same for any spaces between inline elements will be displayed

Comment: specification e.g.: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#white-space-model and http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-formatting, reason: toreadtextinsentenceswithoutwhitespacewouldbeproblematic, and as @Pete said, what `inline` basically means is "like a word in text"

Answer (score 2):

Remove the white space between your li elements.

```
<li><a href="index">Home</a></li><li><a href="Projects">Projects</a></li><li><a href="Settings">Settings</a></li>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7Gu4Y/2/)**

Or put HTML comments (`<!-- -->`) between the list items:

```
<ul class="maina">
    <li><a href="index">Home</a></li><!--
 --><li><a href="Projects">Projects</a></li><!--
 --><li><a href="Settings">Settings</a></li>
</ul>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7Gu4Y/3/)**